# Using scanner to read from console in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have tried using `Scanner` to read from console into a string object and keep adding the data until the user pushes enter twice .How can I improve my code?

```
    String text;

public void Settext() {

    System.out.println("please enter the values for the text :");
    String S;

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    if ((S = scn.next())!= null) {
        text += S.split("\\|");
    }
    scn.close();
}

public String toString() {
    Settext();
    String S = "the output of document class toString method is " + text;

    return S;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: i replace "if " with a "while" but it goes into an infinite loop i am not able to exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of your if statement -

```
int noOfNulls = 0;
while(noOfNulls != 2)
{
    if ((S = scn.next()) != null)
    {
        text += S.split("\\|");
        noOfNulls = 0;
    }
    else
        noOfNulls++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. Does what you describe. Taking in consideration that a user might press Enter Key several times but no consecutively.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String readString = scanner.nextLine();
            String buffer="";
            boolean previusEnter=false;
            while(readString!=null) {


                if (readString.equals("")){
                    if(previusEnter)
                        break;
                    previusEnter=true;
                }
                else
                    previusEnter=false;

                buffer+= readString+"\n";

                if (scanner.hasNextLine())
                    readString = scanner.nextLine();                                   
                else
                    readString = null;
            }
```